# Output Full Lines From a Text File in Powershell 2

Tags: powershell, output, powershell-2.0

I am trying to read a file, then output only lines that start with a specific string to a new file. The issue that I am having is that the lines are long (1000+ chars) and the outputted lines are wrapping. Each full line in the source file needs to be the same full (unbroken) line in the target file.

```
$data = get-content "C:\TEST\INBOUND\DATA\TEST_IMP.TXT"

foreach($line in $data)
{
    if($line.length > 2){

        if($line.substring(0,2) -eq "AZ" )
        { 
            write-host $line | out-file -filepath "C:\TEST\INBOUND\DATA\TEST_OUT."
        }
    }    
}
```

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Content "C:\path\file.txt" | Where-Object {$_ -like "AZ*"} | Out-File "C:\path\outfile.txt" -Append
```